# Robot.delay(int) versus Thread.sleep(long)

Tags: java, multithreading, delay, sleep, awtrobot

I have a program whose only purpose is to drive a `java.awt.Robot` in an infinite loop until an exit condition is met.

The robot performs a number of actions in quick succession, which require a standard UI delay between them. For this, I use `java.awt.Robot.setAutoDelay(int ms)`, which appears to be designed for precisely this purpose.

At other times, however, I need to insert arbitrarily long delays for operations to complete. I appear to have a choice between using `java.awt.Robot.delay(int ms)` or `java.lang.Thread.sleep(long ms)`, and am curious what the differences between them are, and which I should use.

My gut instinct was to keep all my operations in the same "place", and use `java.awt.Robot.delay(int ms)`. However, after thinking about it for a moment, I assumed that `java.awt.Robot.delay(int ms)` would put an operation on the Robot's stack of operations to complete, and if those were my only delays in an infinite loop, I may very quickly, and needlessly, generate an absurdly large queue of events for the Robot.

At that point, I checked [the API for `java.awt.Robot.delay(int ms)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#delay%28int%29), which told me the following:

> Sleeps for the specified time. To catch any `InterruptedException`s that occur, `Thread.sleep()` may be used instead.

Having failed to gain any useful insight into the matter, I elected to ask you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first I would also assume that using `delay()` would generate a large queue of events, in particular after reading the javadoc for `waitForIdle()`:

> Waits until all events currently on the event queue have been processed

but checking the source code of `Robot.delay()` shows that it basically is a `Thread.sleep()`, after checking that the delay time is positive and not more than 1 minute!

Abstract: both solutions are almost the same, use `Thread.sleep()` for delaying longer than 1 minute or catching the InterruptedException.

*after years of programming with Java I found how to sleep without having to catch the InterruptedException (disregarding the overhead of creating a Robot)*

Answer (score 1):

> However, after thinking about it for a moment, I assumed that java.awt.Robot.delay(int ms) would put an operation on the Robot's stack of operations to complete, and if those were my only delays in an infinite loop, I may very quickly, and needlessly, generate an absurdly large queue of events for the Robot.

Your fears are unfounded.  The `delay(int)` method does exactly what the javadoc says it does.  It delays the calling thread rather than inserting a "delay for so long" event onto the Robot instance's queue.